# How to make set of object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an array of people relations (`people1` and `people2`) and i want to get all the peoples in these array. (collection of `p1` and `p2`)

For example - 
i have this array -

```
[
  {p1fName: 'J1', p1lName: 'J1', p2fName: 'J2', p2lName: 'J2'},
  {p1fName: 'J1', p1lName: 'J1', p2fName: 'J3', p2lName: 'J3'},
  {p1fName: 'J3', p1lName: 'J3', p2fName: 'J4', p2lName: 'J4'},
]
```

and i want the result to be like this -

```
[
  {fname: 'J1', lname: 'J1'},
  {fname: 'J2', lname: 'J2'},
  {fname: 'J3', lname: 'J3'},
  {fname: 'J4', lname: 'J4'}
]
```

the identifier of each `people` is the combination of `fName` and `lName`.

now im using Map of string (`${fname}_${lname}`) to the object i want to return (`peopleId`) and in this way im keeping the uniqueness.

do you have any idea how can i do this using Set ?

Thank you

Comment: Please add the `Map` code with `${fname}_${lname}` to the question. Also, https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better option if you already have working code.

Comment: {} !== {}, you can't use a Set for objects.

Comment: loop your array with objects and create a new array with new objects using your desired structure

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const x =[ {p1fName: 'J1', p1lName: 'J1', p2fName: 'J2', p2lName: 'J2'},
  {p1fName: 'J1', p1lName: 'J1', p2fName: 'J3', p2lName: 'J3'},
  {p1fName: 'J3', p1lName: 'J3', p2fName: 'J4', p2lName: 'J4'}
  ]
  
  const transform = data => {
    const [d1,d2] = x.flatMap(({p1fName, p1lName, p2fName, p2lName})=> ([
      {fname: p1fName, lname: p1lName},
      {fname: p2fName, lname: p2lName}
    ]))
    .reduce(([r1,r2],{fname, lname})=>{
      const key = `${fname}_${lname}`
      if (!r1.has(key)) {
        r1.add(key)
        r2.push({fname, lname})
      }
      return [r1,r2]
    }, [new Set(), []])
    return d2
  }
  
  console.log(transform(x))
```

First, you want to flatten your array (input) to {fname, lname} before finding the unique set of {fname, lname}